# Smooth Scrolling with Dropdown Menu to Anchor Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

```
<select>
<option value="#anchor">Anchor</option>
</select>

<a id="anchor">Anchor</a>
```

I'm trying to get it to scroll smoothly, but it hasn't worked so far. The workable tutorials I found online were with regular vertical menus, not a dropdown. Does anyone know how to get this working? I've been using this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('option[value^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you need to scroll to anchor when you change the select value so

1st: change you selector to select and use change event for it

2nd: get selected value by using `$(this).val();`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // no need to use this line
        var target = $(this).val();
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing', function () {  // swing here will work if you include jquery-ui  without that it will not make a effect
            //window.location.hash = target;
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/99sm098e/)

> **Note:** be sure to include jquery

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried it for both firefox and chrome.

Comment: @JudiaValenciaKrakowski I update my answer with demo  if you don't need it to scroll when load just remove .change() from the last of code